# apache 2.4 virtual hosts view same page

Tags: php, apache

I finished my laravel project, I want to host it like this `192.168.1.50:8888` but it shows the same page as `192.168.1.50` which means it go to `"E:/portal/www"` instead of `"E:/portal/www/system/public"`

I did the following on apache configuration

My projects folder `E:/portal/www` contains a laravel project called `system`

I enabled vhosts in `httpd.conf` and did the following changes

```
DocumentRoot "E:/portal/www"
<Directory "E:/portal/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    FcgidWrapper E:/portal/php-7.1.6/php-cgi.exe .php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
Listen 80
Listen 8888

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.50:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot "E:/portal/www"
    <Directory  "E:/portal/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.50:8888>
    ServerName system.dev
    DocumentRoot "E:/portal/www/system/public"
    <Directory  "E:/portal/www/system/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What should I do??

Comment: Make certain your vhosts is being loaded. Can you check `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on?

Comment: or `apachectl restart`

Comment: I I'm using windows server 2012, I restarted the service and restarted the whole OS but nothing happened

Comment: I ran `httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` and it shows both servers correctly, but when I visit `192.168.1.50:8888` it show the same page as `192.168.1.50:80`